# RandomForest classification - closest point to change class

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I'm currently working on a Kaggle dataset regarding [Human Resources Analytics](https://www.kaggle.com/ludobenistant/hr-analytics).

I've cleaned the dataset, benchmark some models. The best one is the RandomForestClassifier, which predict if a employee left the company or not with a good accuracy (around 99%).

Now, I would like to find the most probable employee still in the company who may leave. I used the `predict_proba` method on the train model but this gives me the probability that the employee left or not. It's not the probability for the employee to leave. Moreover, the dataset is the one used for the training.

I have no idea, how to predict this kind of information. In a linear regression for example, I'd have look for the closest point to the estimator but with an ensemble, I don't know.

I attached below a piece of code if you want to try it:

```python
dataset = pd.read_csv("HR.csv")

# Cleanup/Preparation datas
convert_dict = {"high" : 3, "medium": 2, "low": 1}
dataset = dataset.replace({"salary": convert_dict})

dataset = pd.get_dummies(dataset)

X = dataset.drop("left", axis=1)
y = dataset["left"]
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# training best model (I pass the benchmark part)
model = RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=False, n_estimators=50)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
acc = model.score(X_test, y_test)
print(acc)

# Eval
eval_dataset = dataset[dataset["left"] == 0]
X = eval_dataset.drop("left", axis=1)
y = eval_dataset["left"]
X = scaler.transform(X)
y_pred = model.predict_proba(X) # => This is wrong
```

Thanks for your support,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say your model is ~99% accurate, but is that in test? If so great! Now image you have new data coming in that contains all of your data fields, you would be able to use the `predict_proba` method on each obersavtion/s to predict whether or not they left. In this sense you can use this as a simple proxy for will leave as this is the best you have right now.

I will give you a quick hypothesis to test though. Say all things remained the same for an employee, but time continues to pass. You could update the amount of time an employee has spent at a company and see how the probability of them leaving changes over time. Granted this wouldn't be a great method for predicting several years out (as hopefully people grow and the other parameters change), but it would give you a good idea of how long someone would put up with their current status quo, based on the knowledge learned from the training data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ! Yes accuracy is 98.8% with the Test sample and slightly above 99% in CrossValidation. I'll try to extract some entries where employee is still in the company just to get fresh data and try the predict_proba. The thing is, I cannot find the most important one on the complete company as it is (beacuse I still need some employee to train it).

Comment: I've extracted 50 elements, trained the model without them and evaluate the probability in those items. Output looks more clearly more logical (between 50% - 50% to 68% - 32%). I'll focus on this solution for now, Thanks for the solution !

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your question...

> I used the `predict_proba` method on the train model but this gives me the probability that the employee left or not. It's not the probability for the employee to leave.

This is wrong on many levels:

- *philosophically*, since the employee has already either left or not, there is not any actual probability involved here, and that is why the respective data column `left` is actually binary (0/1) and not in the range [0,1]
- *computationally*, you indeed get what the model *would have guessed as a probability of leaving*, after training

On close inspection, the data also seem to suffer from *[class imbalance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235808/binary-classification-with-strongly-unbalanced-classes)* (in simple words, your 1's are much more than your 0's), which calls for more caution and specialised techniques (vanilla accuracy may be misinformative here).

It is not clear what your code does after `#Eval`, why you seem to keep only records with `left==0`, or what exactly `best_1` is (your "best" model, perhaps?). But applying `predict_proba` on your test set `X_test` will indeed give you the model's *probability guess* regarding leaving for these (unseen during training) employees.

Comment: Oops I failed on copy/paste. _best_1_ is my best model based on a GridSearch (not provided here). In eval session, I only kept employees remaining to try to evaluate the possibility that they leave. I imagine that there is pattern and I don't know how close I am to move from the classe 0 to 1. For the unbalance, I don't know exactly because "left" if around 25% of the dataset

Comment: @NicolasM. I am not sure I am following you. You dataset is indeed imbalanced. And if you found the answer even partially useful, upvotes are appreciated (responses take valuable time...)

Comment: Ok I don't know a from where we can say a dataset is unbalanced. Is it 40% vs 60%, 25% vs 75%, 10% vs 90% (this is currently my tought) or 99% vs 1%. Sure you answer is helpful and thanks for it (and I also saw that you edited my post so thanks also for it !)